# How do I get multiple vimwikis to show under "Vimwiki / Open Index" in the gvim menu?

Tags: plugin-vimwiki

I want to work between two vimwiki directories: a private vimwiki and a public vimwiki.

How do I get multiple vimwikis in the gvim `Vimwiki > Open index >`  menu?

In my ~/.vimrc I have the two wikis defined:

```
" vimwiki 
let wiki_1 = {}
let wiki_1.path = '~/vimwiki'
let wiki_1.path_html = '~/vimwiki_html'
let wiki_2 = {}
let wiki_2.path = '~/private'
let wiki_2.path_html = '~/private_html'
let g:vimwiki_list = [wiki_1, wiki_2]
```

In vim and gvim, when I press `\ws` I can see the two options, as I expect:

```
1   ~/vimwiki/                                         
2 * ~/private/
Select Wiki (specify number):
```

However, in gvim the menu only shows one entry, the tilde ( ~ )

[image: gvim menu item Vimwiki > "Open Index" submenu item]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was missing a trailing slash on both `wiki_?.path` values.

I corrected my ~/.vimrc as follows:

```
" vimwiki 
let wiki_1 = {}
let wiki_1.path = '~/vimwiki/'
let wiki_1.path_html = '~/vimwiki_html/'

let wiki_2 = {}
let wiki_2.path = '~/private/'
let wiki_2.path_html = '~/private_html/'

let g:vimwiki_list = [wiki_1, wiki_2]
```

After a trailing slash is added, the correct entries show up in  the gvim `Vimwiki > Open index > menu`

[image: gvim Vimwiki Open index menu with options matching Leaderws]

What threw me was that in vim and gvim when I pressed `\ws` I got the result I expected, yet the gvim menu showed a different set of wikis.  Both methods show the same result set now.

Answer (score 3):

Great tip with the slash and the `\ws`, thx!

I have entered the following into my `.vimrc` (). Hope it helps someone:

```
" Markdown for multiple vimwiki's
"
let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path': '~/Documents/myWiki/', 'syntax': 'markdown', 'ext': '.md'},
                     \ {'path': '~/Documents/myScripts.wiki/', 'syntax': 'markdown', 'ext': '.md'}]
```

And `\ws`:

```
1   /Users/username/Documents/myWiki/
2   /Users/username/Documents/myScripts.wiki/
Select Wiki (specify number):
```

I run `vim` `version 8.2.200` on Mac